# Cypher preventing a relationship from node b to a if the same relation from a to b exist?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to prevent a relationship between two nodes in Neo4j if the same relation from the different side is already present i.e.

`create (a)-[r:Variation]->(b)`

if and only if (b)-[r:Variation]->(a) is not present in the database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your query only does relationship creation (nothing else after this), then just add `WHERE NOT (b)-[:Variation]->(a)` before your CREATE (I'm assuming there's a MATCH to `a` and `b` above this you didn't provide).

But if there's additional logic afterward and you want the query to keep executing whether or not the conditional is met, you may want to take a look at [conditional procs in APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_conditional_cypher_execution), specifically `apoc.do.when()`.